# Pandas Apply Function To Groupby Sub DataFrames

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, apply

Is there a way to apply function to sub-dataframes and not just to columns or rows of the main data?

For example, if I have
  `df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1,2,2,3,3], 'Valid':[0, 0, 0, 1, 1], 'Value':[10, 5, 10, 0, 10]})`

[image: Example DataFrame]

and I want the expected output of
`out = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,3], 'Value':[0, 0, 10]})`
[image: Output]

which is to sum all values which are valid for the ID, then I would like to apply a function of

```
def calc(subDf):
'''
this is doing some inner calculations for the dataframe which is already grouped.
'''
    output = subDf[subDf['Valid']].sum()
    return output
```

Is there a way to to this in the form of `df.groupby('ID').apply(calc)`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need convert column to boolean if necessary and also add column name for filter column for `sum`:

```
def calc(subDf):

    output = subDf.loc[subDf['Valid'].astype(bool), 'Value'].sum()
    return output

df = df.groupby('ID').apply(calc).reset_index(name='Value')
print (df)

   ID  Value
0   1      0
1   2      0
2   3     10
```